# NER Model Training using spacy

Tags: nlp, data-annotations, data-preprocessing, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I am struggling during training an NER model using spacy transformer in GPU. This NER is related to build an accurate CV Parser. The main challenge here is that I can't give a lot of data to this model at once. There are approximately 35 labels to train NER for.
I am getting very poor accuracy which is about 40% after giving 2.5K training data and 500 testing data. I trained 3 separate models to extract NER information. I need to improve it further for two aspects.

1. Accuracy needs to be improved.
2. Response tome should be improved to few seconds which is 45 seconds now.
   I am using Roberta Base model to do NER training.
   Please suggest me ideas. I would also like to understand the config.cfg file for spacy ner training.
   Thank you!!!

I tried simple NER training and transformer based training. I failed to achieve a good accuracy but when I see any video in Youtube or any blog related to NER training, there the accuracy is easily achieved 80 to 90 %.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.